# Unit Test Javascript in ASP.NET MVC and Knockout that accessing Html Helper and Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, knockout.js

I have written a view model using Knockout such as:

```
@model Application.Models.PageModel

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

    var publishUrl = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action<Application.Controllers.PageController>(x => ...;

    var initialData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));

....
```

My question is how can I do unit test just for the javascript as:
the javascript depends on 
- Html Helper (@Html.Raw...) and 
- @Html.Raw(...) and
- Model

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be written in such way it can be unit tested. Create a viewmodel and pass the values to the viewmodel during the creation of the new view model object.

**Define viewmodel**

```
function ViewModel(publishUrl, initialData)
{
   this.publishUrl=publishUrl;
   this.initialData=initialData;
}
```

Create viewmodel object and pass in the values of external dependencies, this way you can test your viewmodel by passing the mock values.

**Create viewmodel and pass in the external dependency values**

```
var _viewModel = new ViewModel (@Html.Raw(Url.Action<Application.Controllers.PageController>(x => ...), @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)) )
```

As you know the viewmodel can be always bound to knockout.

```
ko.applyBindings(_viewModel)
```

All the time you will be testing the ViewModel logic inside it, since its loosly coupled you should be able to pass in any value you need to test the logic inside viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I have restructured my code so that I have PageVm.cshtml that contain the definition of View Model. How can I test this as it is not located in the script folder. I cannot include the view model located in the View directory in QUnit.

Comment: you should create viewmodel file for each view eg., EmployeeViewModel under "\scripts\viewmodel" and include them via bundling concept if you are using MVC 4. Since view model is separate file you should be able to test the script file with Qunit.